# Convert number to date format in R?

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

I have data table called my_data and its C column is date which is in number format e.g 4021. I want to convert it to date format 01/03/2011. My code is given below

`a <- as.Date(as.numeric(my_data$c), origin="1900-01-01")`

It gives me the solution but it changes my dataframe. Is there any best solution?

Comment: Please share a piece of your data frame so that others can help you better.

Answer (score -1):

I also have this issue.
My format is 201803 which is ym. I use package `lubridate`.

```
ym(201803)
> ym(201803)
[1] "2018-03-01"
```

It will automatically add the first day of the month as the missing date. But it was ok for me.
You could search `lubridate` cheatsheet online for more details.